# CCS conditional document direction

Tags: css, right-to-left

I want to let the user switch the whole document between LTR and RTL. Some CSS properties have `start` and `end` values that follow the direction of the document. Most geometrical relations are though absolute.
I want to do something like this if possible, in plain CSS without Javascript and without reloading the document:

> if <body> dir is ltr
> use padding-**left**: 65px;
> if <body> dir is rtl
> use padding-**right**: 65px;

**Edit:** [Here is i complete list of logical properties and values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties), so adding a conditional properties may not be needed altogether. Note though that some or all will not work on few years old browsers. My 4yo Galaxy s8 for instance, has never updated its native browser who did not support logical.

**Edit2:** See now that `float: inline-start and inline-end` are only supported by Firefox, so back to conditional CSS,

Comment: do you have a dir property on body or not ?

Comment: This feels like `body { padding-inline-start: 65px; }` should work, regardless? Reference: [`padding-inline-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-start).

Comment: HDMI91: No, I tried first with `style` `direction`. Your reply below require `dir` and I realized that after some attempts.

Comment: David Thomas: you are right. I scanned all my style elements and replaced all `left` and `right` with appropriate `start` and `end` (with or without `-inline-`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body[dir=rtl] #some-id{
  padding-right: 65px;
  color: red;
}
    
body[dir=ltr] #some-id{
  padding-left: 65px;
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<body dir="ltr">
    <div id="some-id">test</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case it should apply to all `label`s inside all `div`s of a `class`: `body[dir=ltr] .toggle-group label {...`. Doesn't seem to work, the labels have no CSS properties.

Comment: I was wrong in the previous comment: the `body` needs a `dir` statement, not a CSS `direction property.`

Comment: And it seams that most properties has `-inline-start` and `-inline-end`. As to the `left` property, it works by replacing it with `inset-inline-start`, though I am not sure this is right.

Comment: Finally got to implement it, Firefox doesn't like this: "*When rendering the <html> element, the used values of CSS properties “writing-mode”, “direction”, and “text-orientation” on the <html> element are taken from the computed values of the <body> element, not from the <html> element’s own values. Consider setting these properties on the :root CSS pseudo-class. For more information see “The Principal Writing Mode” in https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/#principal-flow*"